# Find eight elements in S6 that commute with (12)(34)(56). Do they form a subgroup of S6?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I know the question has been asked and answered many times, but I am trying to shore up my understanding of this concept.
Given the questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149940/find-eight-elements-commute-with-one-element-in-s6/1150838#1150838) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922995/find-eight-elements-in-s-6-that-commute-with-123456?rq=1), does this mean that I could rearrange the bottom row of the array form and each rearrangement can be written in the form of 2-cycles?  Also, each rearrangement is guaranteed to commute?  Essentially, $\sigma\times(12)(34)(56)=(12)(34)(56)\times \sigma$ for all $\sigma$?

#### Examples:

$\begin{equation} \sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5& a_6 \end{array}\right)=(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)(a_5a_6)\end{equation}$  
$\begin{equation} \sigma_1=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1&2&3&5&4&6 \end{array}\right)=(12)(35)(46)\end{equation}$  
$\begin{equation} \sigma_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1&2&3&6&4&5 \end{array}\right)=(12)(36)(45)\end{equation}$

Comment: For $\sigma$ to commute with (12)(34)(56) you need $\sigma \times (12)(34)(56)=(12)(34)(56) \times \sigma.$ Note how the $\sigma$ occurs on the left on one side, on the right on the other. So your equation with $\sigma$ only there once is not what is to be looked at.

Comment: Oops, fixing post now.

Comment: The cycle versions to the right of your three examples are not right. For example $\sigma_1=(45)$ since it only switches 4,5 and fixes all the others.